# Speed up nested for-loops

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply

I'm trying to combine the info from a number of data frames to fill one big data frame. The first dataframe is like an overview of all human genes:

```
gene_id chromosome  gene_start  gene_end
ENSG00000116396 1   110753965   110825722
ENSG00000228217 1   118320709   118321128
ENSG00000261716 1   149816065   149820591
ENSG00000223562 1   211355498   211356446
ENSG00000239859 1   36171626    36171875
ENSG00000197921 1   2460184     2461684
ENSG00000232237 1   201083081   201096312
ENSG00000212257 1   65488651    65488757
ENSG00000158887 1   161274525   161279762
ENSG00000238122 1   108803818   108816311
ENSG00000215846 1   159246293   159247282
ENSG00000266763 1   26238240    26238313
ENSG00000228634 1   32398621    32399576
ENSG00000177614 1   230457392   230561475
ENSG00000163462 1   155145873   155157447
ENSG00000204481 1   13668269    13673511
```

Secondly, I have a number of files (516 of them), containing data like this:

```
Sample  Chromosome  Start   End Num_Probes  Segment_Mean
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   61735   82170           9       0.2560
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   82315   16869363        8678    -0.1199
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   16871278    17087292    85      -0.5386
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   17089349    17209603    23      -0.0807
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   17210652    17262232    57      0.2680
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   17262247    25583341    5240    -0.1228
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   25593128    25646986    28      -1.8216
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   25661501    30738534    2398    -0.0942
UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930 1   30739299    30745210    7       -1.3117
```

Now, I would like to create some sort of loop, to take each gene in the first data frame. Then I would like to loop through all 516 data frames while checking the place of the gene.

So for each gene and each file, I would like to compare the start and end of the gene with the start and end of each sample segment, provided that they are on the same chromosome. If this is the case, I want to take the segment mean and put it in one big new dataframe with the gene_id's as rownames and the names of the files as column names.

This is the code I already have:

```
for(gene in 1:100){
  gene_id    <- genome[gene, 1]
  chromosome <- genome[gene, 2]
  gene_start <- genome[gene, 3]
  gene_end   <- genome[gene, 4]

  for(name in 1:length(dataframe_names)){
    df <- get(dataframe_names[name])
    for(segment in 1:nrow(df)){
      if(chromosome == as.character(df[segment,2])){
        if(gene_start > df[segment,3] && gene_start < df[segment,4] && gene_end > df[segment,3] && gene_end < df[segment,4]){
          data_matrix[gene,name] <- df[segment, 6]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code works, but it's really slow, considering that there are 57 773 genes. A test run with 100 genes took 1 hour, so a complete run would probably take 2-3 weeks...

I think using the `apply`-family will speed things up, but I've never used them before so I don't really know how to do it. Examples on the internet always use things like `sum` or `mean`, but I don't want to these kind of things, I just want to compare the numbers. Also, I don't know which one of the `apply`-family suits my needs best.

You guys wanna help me out or get on the right track?

Comment: It would help in your example to provide snp segments that overlap genes, and to clarify whether you're expecting no more than 1 snp segment per gene (this is implied by using 'gene_id' as row.name, since row.names are supposed to be unique).

Comment: @Arun -- I don't understand the purpose of your editing the Sample column; it seems like these identifiers are meaningful and one will only introduce errors by making them 'pretty'.

Comment: @MartinMorgan, in this example, all the identifiers were identical. So, not sure what errors it'll introduce on 'this example data'. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Arun -- it seems like a pointless edit, losing information that is important to the OP. If identity were important, and all are identical, then the logical thing to do would be to remove them entirely! Also if you were the down-vote on this post, then reconsider or at least justify -- the OP provides a reasonably reproducible example and question, even if at first blush the title reads as though it is a duplicate of many other StackOverflow questions. Probably the comments section is not the appropriate place to have these conversations, so sorry for that.

Comment: @Arun, I know these identifiers are identical. It's the way those files are build. I didn't create the files, but downloaded them in this format.

Comment: @Arun, Actually, the identifier is also the name of the respective file

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need to do is stop reinventing the wheel. Get familiar with the bioconductor packages `IRanges`, `GenomicRanges` (and `Biostrings` for completeness, although not for this particular problem). Once you get GenomicRanges look into the findOverlaps family of functions.

Since your exmple data doesn't actually have any overlaps I modified it like so

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene_id = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 
   4L), .Label = c("ENSG00000207157", "ENSG00000223116", "ENSG00000229483", 
   "ENSG00000232849", "ENSG00000233440", "ENSG00000235205", "ENSG00000252952"
   ), class = "factor"), chromosome = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
   13L, 13L), gene_start = c(23551994L, 23708313L, 23726725L, 23743974L, 
   23791571L, 23817659L, 93708910L), gene_end = c(23552136L, 23708703L, 
   23726825L, 23744736L, 23791673L, 23821323L, 93710179L)), .Names = c("gene_id", 
   "chromosome", "gene_start", "gene_end"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
   -7L))
 df2 <- structure(list(Sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L), .Label = "UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930", class = "factor"), 
Chromosome = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Start = c(61735L, 
82315L, 16871278L, 17089349L, 17210652L, 17262247L, 25593128L, 
25661501L, 30739299L), End = c(82170L, 16869363L, 17087292L, 
17209603L, 17262232L, 25583341L, 25646986L, 30738534L, 30745210L
), Num_Probes = c(9L, 8678L, 85L, 23L, 57L, 5240L, 28L, 2398L, 
7L), Segment_Mean = c(0.256, -0.1199, -0.5386, -0.0807, 0.268, 
-0.1228, -1.8216, -0.0942, -1.3117)), .Names = c("Sample", 
"Chromosome", "Start", "End", "Num_Probes", "Segment_Mean"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
df1$chromosome <- 1
df1[6,4] <- 30745215 # to show what happens when there are multiple overlaps
```

Now to get the overlaps

```
library(GenomicRanges)
Genes <- GRanges(df1$chromosome,
             IRanges(df1$gene_start, df1$gene_end), genes=df1$gene_id)

# make a list of the 512 others, and read 1 one for example
files <- list.files(pattern="csv") # assuming they are .csv files
snps0 <- read.csv(files[[1]])
snps  <- GRanges(snps0$Chromosome, IRanges(snps0$Start, snps0$End),
                 Segment_Mean=snps0$Segment_Mean)
olaps <- findOverlaps(query=snps, subject=Genes)
```

Once you have the overlaps you can use that as a basis to merge the original data frames

```
olaps2 <- as.data.frame(olaps)
df1$Row <- rownames(df1)
NewDF <- merge(df1,olaps2,by.x="Row",by.y="subjectHits",all=T,sort=F)
df2$Row <- rownames(df2)
NewDF2 <- merge(NewDF,df2,by.x="queryHits",by.y="Row",all.x=T,sort=F)[,c(-1,-2)] 
# drop the first 2 columns because they were just temporary for merging purposes
head(NewDF2,2)
      gene_id chromosome gene_start gene_end
1 ENSG00000223116          1   23551994 23552136
2 ENSG00000207157          1   23726725 23726825
                                                   Sample Chromosome    Start
1 UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930          1 17262247
2 UNDID_p_TCGA_353_354_355_37_NSP_GenomeWideSNP_6_H10_1376930          1 17262247
   End Num_Probes Segment_Mean
1 25583341       5240      -0.1228
2 25583341       5240      -0.1228
```